# Why doesn't this word boundary Regular Expression match as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a set of words I want to match in a given string.

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

I only want to match the complete word, so have setup the following test case.

```
var data = "I love foo, it's barb."
var words = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

How can I match just whole words?

```js
var data = 'I love foo its barb.';
var words = ['foo', 'bar'];
var matches = data.match(new RegExp('(\b' + words.join('\b|\b') + '\b)', 'ig'));
console.log(matches);

var data = 'I love foo its barb.';
var words = ['foo', 'bar'];
var matches = data.match(new RegExp('(' + words.join('|') + ')', 'ig'));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Your current backslashes just result in unnecessarily escaped `b`s, without any *actual* backslashes appearing in the resulting string

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of the need to double escape :)